# Работа с картами на питоне

Tags: python, google-maps

Есть файл .kml  с полигонами и отдельно стоящими точками, нужно (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C2PkgyC_bmyhUefR-JsnTbQ4QfqtUtxT/view?usp=sharing):

1. В питоне написать скрипт, который объединяет все полигоны в один мультиполигон и проверяет все точки на принадлежность к этому полигону.
2. Запринтить только те, которые не принадлежат мультиполигону.

Все, что я могу  - это прочесть файл:

```
from pykml.factory import write_python_script_for_kml_document
with open('file.kml') as f:
    folder = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder

for pm in folder.Placemark:
    print(pm.name)
```

Comment: @Danis так я вообще не знаю , как к нему подступиться:((